# oracle sql developer empty mrp_orders_v

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle database

Oracle Applications : 11.5.10.2

There are table apps.mrp_orders_v that I can't query in "oracle Sql developer"
"select * from apps.mrp_orders_v" but no data is returned

The funny thing is when I use the same credentials thru ODBC and microsoft Access or Power query in excel then I can see the data

Any idea?

There are lots of other tables where I can see data from the oracle database thru oracle sql developer

Kind regards

John

select * from apps.mrp_orders_v

Rows from the table

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database?

Comment: Yes i am sure og that